# Restrict FindInstance to exact value

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

I would like to restrict the FindInstance function to exact values (ex. 2Pi/3)

The following doesn't work

```
FindInstance[a*Cos[b  x] +  c*Cos[d  x]^2 == 0 && ExactNumberQ[x], {x, a, b, c, d}, Reals, 2]
```

Thanks

Comment: `Q` functions don't work in this setting, for example `FindInstance[PrimeQ[x], x, PositiveIntegers]` won't work because it's evaluated to False and Q functions are more of a programmatic construct than a boolean predicate you can put in a formula - it's kind of hard to explain.

Answer (score 2):

If you first do the following, you'll get a simpler form of the equation which removes the $\cos^2$ using the double angle formula:

```
eqn = a*Cos[b x ] + c*Cos[d x]^2 == 0;
simplerEqn = FullSimplify[TrigReduce[eqn]];
(* c + 2 a Cos[b x] + c Cos[2 d x] == 0 *)
```

Then `FindInstance` has a better chance at finding solutions without weird `Root` objects:

```
sols = FindInstance[simplerEqn, {a, b, c, d, x}, Reals, 2]

(** {
  {a -> 1/20 (-551 - 551 Cos[195447/25]) Sec[54253/50],
   b -> 239/10, c -> 551/10, d -> 861/10, x -> -(227/5)},

  {a -> 1/20 (663 + 663 Cos[39211/25]) Sec[108611/50],
   b -> 313/10, c -> -(663/10), d -> 113/10, x -> -(347/5)}
} **)
```

Verify with `TrigReduce[eqn[[1]] /. sols[[1]]]` and `TrigReduce[eqn[[1]] /. sols[[2]]]` and they both give zero .

Answer (score 1):

Five variables are too many for `FindInstance`, so

```
Table[FindInstance[a*Cos[b x]+c*Cos[d x]^2==0&&x!=0,{x,a,b,d},Reals],{c,0,1}]
```

> `{{{x -> -(15/2), a -> 0, b -> 171/10, d -> -(103/5)}}, {{x -> -(1/10), a -> -81, b -> 45 \[Pi], d -> -95 \[Pi]}}}`

As we see, `FindInstance` tries to find simple solutions as far as it is possible.